# Seleccionar item en BottomNavigationView al entrar

Tags: android, menú, android-bottom-nav-view

Tengo un `BottomNavigationView` y lo que quiero es que cuando entre a la app el item seleccionado no sea el primero.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Aquí tengo el XML pero como digo me aparece seleccionado el item de contactos, el cual quiero es el item de Perfil que aparezca seleccionado...

[image: Imagen de referencia...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen dos opciones:

Puedes usar el id del elemento que desees sea preseleccionado al inicio y usar el método [setSelectedItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int)).

Por ejemplo si deseas que un elemento con id llamado `my_menu_item_contactos` sea el seleccionado al inicio definelo de esta forma:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.my_menu_item_contactos);
```

De la documentación:

> **[setSelectedItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#setSelectedItemId(int))** Establece la ID del elemento del menú seleccionado. Esto se comporta como tocar un elemento.

---

Otra forma de realizar esto es usar el método [performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()).

Obten la vista del elemento a preseleccionar y llama el método [performClick()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performClick()):

```
View view = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.my_menu_item_contactos);
view.performClick();
```